# How should i write a throttle decorator for function attribute?

Tags: javascript, decorator, throttling

I want to write a throttle decorator for a function attribute?But i'm stucked in the closure issues.

My code is as follows:

```
function throttle(timecount) {
    return function (value, { name, kind }) {
        let origin = value
        if (kind === 'method') {
            return function (args) {
                setTimeout(function (args) {
                    // Following 'this' is always Timeout closure, how shoould i do ???
                    origin.apply(this, args)
                }, timecount)
            }
        }
    }
}

class D {
    message = "hello!";

    @throttle(1000)
    m() {
        console.log('excutet', this.message);
    }
}

let y = new D('sss');
y.m(); // i got undefined ???
```

How should get the right context and get the right answer?